# Function to remove list of tuple with same elements but different order

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

Say I have  list of tuples such as

`[(1,2),(2,1),(3,5)]`

How would I define a function so that a tuple with similar elements but different ordering is removed? So the list becomes

`[(1,2),(3,5)]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`nubBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3anubBy) with an equality function that compares two tuples with swapped or unswapped equal elements as equal. [The `swap` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Tuple.html#v%3aswap) makes this easier:

```
nubSwapped :: (Eq a) => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
nubSwapped = nubBy $ \a b -> a == b || swap a == b
```